# Angular ng-options with track by creates unknown option element

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-track-by

My goal here is to generate a select list that has the option values set to one of my objects properties.  When adding the track by binding option to the ng-options directive an unknown option element is created and it is the only option that ever shows selected.  This behavior is in angular v1.3 (which is the version I'm using).  In v1.4 it still creates the unknown item but will change the display to show a different selected item.  In neither case does it set the initial state of the dropdown to correspond to the model value.

[ng-options Track By example v1.3](http://plnkr.co/edit/BBawi0BkQoJr1Qms7ruR?p=preview)

```
  <body>
    <script>
    angular.module('plunker', [])
    .controller("MyCntrl",   function($scope) {
        $scope.myColor = "rd"; // red
        $scope.colors = [
          {name:'black', code:'bk'},
          {name:'white',  code:'wh'},
          {name:'red', code:'rd'},
          {name:'blue', code:'bl'},
          {name:'yellow', code:'yl'}
        ];
    });
  </script>
    <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
      <select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.code as color.name for     color in colors track by color.code"></select><br>
      <hr/>
      <span>Currently selected: {{myColor}}</span>
   </div>
</body>
```

In v1.4 it still does not set the initial state but upon select a new value it will change the display.  I find it strange that this doesn't work and that it's not been an issue.

[Angular v1.4 Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mDMtrBf9BJXxdChR7Zzp?p=preview)

In case you're wondering, we want this so that the the option values are known codes that our test automation can key on and the only thing we want the model value to be is the code.  Seems like a a fairly standard thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value to be the entire object in your controller.

```
   $scope.myColor ={name:'red', code:'rd'};
```

Then it will properly select.

Comment: The problem is that my model (which comes from the db) only has the code.  The label comes from a localized content management system.  So, all I need in the model to both set and retrieve the selected value is the code.

Comment: I'm not sure why that is a problem.  If your code looks like the example you give above then this is the solution regardless of if you only have or need the code.  If your model contains objects that have both the name and code, and initially all you have the code, simply find the object in your list with that code and set it to the current value. When you are sending data back to your application just pull out the code of the selected item and send just that.

Comment: Yes, that's doable but requires more coding that shouldn't be needed.  No reason that the list shouldn't be bindable to just the code when you add track by to the binding statement.